# A singly rooted hierarchy makes it much easier to implement a garbage collector

Tags: java, oop

this is the Quote from **Thinking in java** book

> A singly rooted hierarchy makes it much easier to implement a garbage
>   collector (which is conveniently built into Java). The necessary
>   support can be installed in the base class, and the garbage collector
>   can thus send the appropriate messages to every object in the system.
>   Without a singly rooted hierarchy and a system to manipulate an object
>   via a reference, it is difficult to implement a garbage collector.

How can the garbage collector **send** the appropriate messages to every object in the system.Yes every class derive from object but how is that message sent?

What is that message?

what do we achieve from this?

---

**NOTE**

This question is different from my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109983/does-unified-type-system-help-for-doing-garbage-collection) question..Although i didn't found any proper answer for it too!

Comment: The question really is what they mean by "singly rooted". It can't mean "there is a single object that is the GC root" because that isn't true in Java, there are multiple GC roots of many different types. (Though internally they could all be collected into a structure which can then serve as the single GC root.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the author refers to the [`finalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) method, that every Object has, and that is called by the garbage collector. Sending a message = Calling a method.

Comment: thxx for your ans..but i guess `finalize()` is not guaranteed to be called by the `GC`..So `finalize()` is not an important part of `GC`..author says this `without singly rooted hierarchy it is difficult to implement a garbage collector.`..i guess it is something that the compiler hides and uses it internally

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be called, but having it in Object allows the GC to call it on any object.

Answer (score 1):

The type `Object` includes some "hidden" fields which inform the GC of things it needs to know about any object derived from `Object`.  I don't know why the quoted text uses the term "message", but for the GC to know what to do with a chunk of memory it has to know what that chunk of memory represents.  If different kinds of object had different headers and the only way of knowing what a chunk of memory represented was to know what kind of reference identified it, the GC would have a much tougher job.